# Kotlin And Overloading

Tags: oop, kotlin, polymorphism

I'm new at Kotlin and I found that in Kotlin you can create a method where a parameter has a default value.
For example

```
fun something( name: String, gender: String? = null): String{
return if(gender != null) {
      doSomething
    } else {
      doSomethingElse
    }
```

That makes me wonder, what's the best option in cases that the parameter could be null or empty?. Is this a bad practice?
Personally, I consider the correct way of solving cases like these it's to apply oop overloading. Any clue?

Comment: Providing default values is the same as overloading, except more concise and clear so it should be preferred.

Comment: But isn't it against the fundamentals of object-oriented programming?

Comment: This is just a different syntax for overloading that makes it easier to read and reduces code duplication. What fundamental do you see it as breaking?

Comment: I'd not say breaking but adding more code (in this case ifs) looks as bad as code duplication. Consider the case of having 5 parameters in which 4 of them can be null. Solving that case similar to this, wouldn't it be messy? In that case, I'd prefer to have different methods with different signatures. Just, my two cent

Comment: I was talking about it more generally. In your case if `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse` really have nothing in common, then maybe separate functions makes more sense for clarity.

Comment: You don't have to use `null` as the default value, if there's another value that would make sense — and then you wouldn't have to make the type nullable.

Comment: The default value should be something that makes sense to use if the caller does not provide one.